# Including additional source locations for chekstyle in ant task

Tags: java, ant, checkstyle

I am running checkstyle checks from an ant task. I have configured both properly and can run the task without any problems.

But I have another project/folder with additional source files (lets call them third party sources) which are referenced from within my source files (primary source). I want checkstyle to only **check the primary sources**, but it needs the **third party sources in the classpath** or somehow, otherwise I get ClassNotFound Errors.

**Any suggestions how to do this?**

My configuration in ant looks like the following:

```
<checkstyle config="sun_checks.xml" failOnViolation="false" >
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java" />
    <formatter type="xml" toFile="${report.dir}/checkstyle_sun.xml" />
</checkstyle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a classpath parameter you can set for the checkstyle task:

> classpath      The classpath to use when
>   looking up classes. Defaults to the
>   current classpath.